# Undesirable Display of Google Maps

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps

I have a WordPress single post page that displays Google Map locations for business listings. I am unhappy with the current display of each business map as it produces a big grey space that shows no location information. This is the undesired picture:

[image: dull grey map]

I would like it to appear like anything at all that closely matches the picture below. This one is colourful and one can of course clearly see roads and landscape features etc.

[image: colourful map]

The code I`m using is:

```
}

if( jQuery('.singlebigmaptrigger').length !=0 ){
    $lat = jQuery('.singlebigmaptrigger').data("lat");
    $lan = jQuery('.singlebigmaptrigger').data("lan");
    "use strict";
    if($lan != '' && $lat != ''){
    function init(){var e={zoom:21,scrollwheel:!1,center:new google.maps.LatLng($lat,$lan),styles:[{featureType:"administrative",elementType:"labels.text.fill",stylers:[{color:"#444444"}]},{featureType:"landscape",elementType:"all",stylers:[{color:"#f2f2f2"}]},{featureType:"poi",elementType:"all",stylers:[{visibility:"off"}]},{featureType:"road",elementType:"all",stylers:[{saturation:-100},{lightness:45}]},{featureType:"road.highway",elementType:"all",stylers:[{visibility:"simplified"}]},{featureType:"road.arterial",elementType:"labels.icon",stylers:[{visibility:"off"}]},{featureType:"transit",elementType:"all",stylers:[{visibility:"off"}]},{featureType:"water",elementType:"all",stylers:[{color:"#b7ecf0"},{visibility:"on"}]}]},l=document.getElementById("singlepostmap"),t=new google.maps.Map(l,e);new google.maps.Marker({position:new google.maps.LatLng($lat,$lan),icon:""+$pinicon+"",map:t,title:""})}google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,"load",init);
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend for you to play and try different zoom levels and pick what's best for your application. You can learn more about Zoom Levels here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#zoom-levels

Comment: Can you see any error message in the browser console? Can you check status codes of requests that sends google maps in the network tab of console?